# Store date as "yyyy-MM-dd" in Mongoose via Material UI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, date, mongoose, datepicker

As I'm not exactly used to work with dates on Javascript, it's been quite hard to tackle it without asking for help, and I've been struggling for hours on this.

My goal is to choose a date using Material UI DatePicker and store it as a `string` following the `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format.

In my last attempt, I tried this:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    rating: 0,
    review: "",
    date: Date(),
  });
```

Then, in DatePicker:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
  <DesktopDatePicker
    label="Watched on"
    inputFormat="MMM dd, yyyy"
    disableMaskedInput={true}
    name="date"
    value={userData.date}
    onChange={(date) => {
      setUserData((prevValue) => {
        const dateWatched = startOfDay(date);

        return {
          ...prevValue,
          date: dateWatched.toISOString().slice(0, 10),
        };
      });
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

If I `console.log(dateWatched.toISOString().slice(0, 10)`, when I pick a date it logs correctly. However, the date displayed on DatePicker mismatches. So, let's say I choose December 14, 2021. It logs `2021-12-14` like I wanted, but the DatePicker will show December 13, 2021. For the record, my local time is GMT -03:00, and I think this may be the culprit. I want to take time zones out of the way, so no matter where you are and the time of the day, you'll always get the correct date string saved on Mongoose and displayed correctly on DatePicker.

note: I'm using `date-fns` library.

Comment: The timezone is how the browser knows what you mean by dec 14 2021 12:00 AM (your time zone). It's how if another user's browser in a different part of the world, where dec 14 2021 12:00 AM is let's say, dec 13 2021 9:00 PM would have the correct date loaded in their calendar? The point is keep the time zone, keep it in utc/iso. Store the date as utc/iso. That way it can load consistently in the browser, as the browser can convert utc to local time and display the right month/day/year local to you.

Comment: I get it. It really makes sense. But storing it as UTC wouldn't make it time zone dependent? I mean, in my app (which has a diary section) when I render the component that shows date, won't it display different dates depending on the user's time zone instead of a "fixed" date like I want? Because that kind of happened when I changed my pc time zone to test it.

Comment: Don't think of it as "fixed". If you took a date string that's iso/utc from your database that represents 12-14-2021 12:00 AM yourTimeZone, and did `const theDate = new Date(theUtcDateString)` and then `console.log(date.toISOString())`, even in different parts of the world, it would back to the same same initial value. If you don't store the remaining parts, including the offset/timezone, it will be different date depending on the users time zone. All you need to do, if you don't want to show hours/seconds/meridian, is to just format via the input props.

Comment: You helped me to understand why my reasoning was wrong. Thanks!